# Remove whitespace before the_excerpt();

Tags: excerpt, formatting

I need to delete the whitespace that `the_excerpt();` function returns me. I noticed it gives me whitespace before the whole text only where in the page images goes first and only after goes text.

I tried `str_replace();` and `trim();` none of them helped.

[image: The image of how it looks]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by the line break between the first image in the post and the body content of the post. Just delete the one line of space between the two and it will working fine.

Answer (score 3):

This filter removes all possible whitespace at the beginning of the excerpt, including `&nbsp;`.

```
add_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', 'wpse162725_ltrim_excerpt' );

function wpse162725_ltrim_excerpt( $excerpt ) {
    return preg_replace( '~^(\s*(?:&nbsp;)?)*~i', '', $excerpt );
}
```